# Как найти маску, если известен IP и адрес сети?

Tags: ip

Как найти маску, если известен IP и адрес сети?

Answer (score 0):

Маска задается классом сети, если не указано другое. Рассмотрим `IP` адрес

- Если первый квадрант меньше `128`, то это сеть класса `А`, маска: `255.0.0.0`
- Первый квадрант меньше `192`, класс В, маска: `255.255.0.0`
- Первый квадрант меньше `224`, класс С, маска: `255.255.255.0`

Остальные адреса зарезервированы, либо используются для мультикаста

**Подробнее:** [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Классовая_адресация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: квадрант? это что то новенькое. Плюс, маски давно уже не ограничиваются тремя подсетями.

Comment: Да, поэтому я и сказал, если не указано иное